Lenovo ThinkPad P14s Gen 4 randomly reboots, same with P16s Gen 2 (Nvidia RTX A500)
Hello Ubuntu community,
I’m experiencing random shutdowns and reboots on my Lenovo ThinkPad P14s Gen 4 running Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, and I’m looking for help in diagnosing the issue. These reboots happen suddenly, without any freezing or warning, and I’ve been unable to reproduce the issue on demand.
System Specifications:
Model: Lenovo ThinkPad P14s Gen 4
Processor: Intel i7-1370P vPro (13th Generation)
RAM: 32 GB
Storage: 1 TB SSD
Graphics: NVIDIA RTX A500 4GB GDDR6, currently with nouveau driver, but also teste with proprietary nvidia 550
Ubuntu Version: 24.04 LTS
Kernel Version: 6.8.0-45-generic
Problem:
The laptop randomly shuts down and reboots without freezing. This can happen multiple times a day or less frequently, without a clear pattern. It occurs during both light tasks but also heavier usage, and I cannot replicate the problem consistently.
There is almost no load on the system, since I mostly use it to go remote via Remmina.
Fan is mostly silent, except when starting. Sometimes, I can work for days without a crash, sometimes, it crashes multiple times per day...
The error logs show quite a lot of errors. Especially the HANDLING IBECC MEMORY ERROR was telling me maybe a memory error. But I did memtest etc.
A few logs are atteched at the end, but please let me know, if you need any further information.
Steps I’ve Already Tried:
Mem-Tests:
I did memtest86+ over night with 10 loops. No errors in the memory
Stress Testing:
Ran CPU (stress --cpu 20 --timeout 300) and GPU stress tests (FurMark_2.3.0.0_linux64), but the system remained stable during testing and didn’t reproduce the issue.
Drivers and Display:
Initially thought the issue might be related to MS Teams, but crashes still occur when Teams is not in use, althouht it feels like it happens most when i MS Teams calls. It does not change if I use it in a browser (with and without hardaware acceleration) or via teams-for-linux / teams-for-linux --disableGpu. But it also happens when teams is not running / not in a call. When I only user the browser for example with very low load.
I now suspect the external screen connected via HDMI might be involved, though I haven’t confirmed it.
I have the problems with X11 and Wayland, using both the nouveau open source driver and different versions of the NVIDIA proprietary drivers (nvidia-driver-550, proprietary, tested), but the shutdowns happen regardless of the combination.
System Updates:
All packages and kernels are up-to-date. All Firwmare is up to date
Log Review:
Checked /var/log/syslog and /var/log/kern.log, but nothing conclusive was found before the shutdowns.
Certification:
According to this post (https://ubuntu.com/certified/202306-31718), the Lenovo ThinkPad P14s Gen 4 is even Ubuntu-certified for 22.04 LTS. While I’m running 24.04 LTS, I assume the certification should apply without significant issues.
Looking for Help:
I’m looking for insights or troubleshooting suggestions, specifically:
Any potential causes for random shutdowns and reboots, particularly related to external displays or graphics.
Recommendations on further diagnostics or log files that could help identify the problem.
Any kernel parameters or configuration changes that could stabilize the system.
Thanks in advance for any help!
Best regards,
Ketos
x@dexdev:~$ sudo dmesg | grep -i error
[sudo] password for x: 
[    1.533738] RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized.
[    5.862150] EDAC igen6 MC1: HANDLING IBECC MEMORY ERROR
[    5.862153] EDAC igen6 MC0: HANDLING IBECC MEMORY ERROR

x@dexdev:~$ grep -i "error\|fail" /var/log/kern.log
2024-07-24T06:39:35.891513+02:00 dexdev kernel: pci 0000:03:00.0: ROM [mem size 0x00080000 pref]: failed to assign
2024-07-24T06:39:35.891712+02:00 dexdev kernel: RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized.
2024-07-24T06:39:35.891973+02:00 dexdev kernel: EDAC igen6 MC1: HANDLING IBECC MEMORY ERROR
2024-07-24T06:39:35.891975+02:00 dexdev kernel: EDAC igen6 MC0: HANDLING IBECC MEMORY ERROR
2024-07-24T06:39:35.892036+02:00 dexdev kernel: thermal thermal_zone8: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
2024-07-24T06:39:35.892038+02:00 dexdev kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to send firmware data (-71)
2024-07-24T06:39:35.892038+02:00 dexdev kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-19)
2024-07-24T06:39:35.892038+02:00 dexdev kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: FW download error recovery failed (-19)
2024-07-24T06:39:35.892039+02:00 dexdev kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-19)
2024-07-24T06:39:35.892039+02:00 dexdev kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Reading supported features failed (-19)
2024-07-24T06:39:35.892040+02:00 dexdev kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Error reading debug features
2024-07-24T06:39:35.892040+02:00 dexdev kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: sending frame failed (-19)
2024-07-24T06:39:35.892040+02:00 dexdev kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to read MSFT supported features (-19)
2024-07-24T07:34:04.143778+02:00 dexdev kernel: pci 0000:03:00.0: ROM [mem size 0x00080000 pref]: failed to assign
2024-07-24T07:34:04.144218+02:00 dexdev kernel: RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized.
2024-07-24T07:34:04.144566+02:00 dexdev kernel: EDAC igen6 MC1: HANDLING IBECC MEMORY ERROR
2024-07-24T07:34:04.144570+02:00 dexdev kernel: EDAC igen6 MC0: HANDLING IBECC MEMORY ERROR
2024-07-24T07:34:04.144706+02:00 dexdev kernel: thermal thermal_zone8: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)


I have the same problem since I upgraded to 24.04, and on my side I had to install and boot the 6.5 kernel from Ubuntu 23.10 to be able to use this computer…
Some thoughts: as @user535733 said bellow, the most probable cause for an unexpected reset is a hardware issue; and I did notice that each time it resets unexpectedly, the fans go crazy; so I'm currently suspecting some sensors, fan management, ACPI communications, /proc reporting, etc., changes  between 6.5 and 6.8 kernels.

@progfou I agree. The problem happens even on Ubuntu 22.04.5 but only after I apply all the current updates. It's a HW/SW combo problem.

Having the same issue on a Thinkpad T16 Gen2, after upgrading to 24.04.1 (using KDE Neon). One reliable way of triggering the random poweroffs are Youtube videos.

I am here to report the same issue . My laptop randomly restarts. This happens after I upgraded my Ubuntu from 22 to 24 and now it becomes now very annoying I am not be able to find a root cause or even a pattern for this issue but I am still investigating , my laptop is Lenovo ThinkPad P16s Gen 2  equipped with 13th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-1370P × 20  and 64 GB. I have the errors that you shared in your log file

There's also a thread on the Lenovo Forums discussing this (or a very similar) issue with the same chipset: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Other-Linux-Discussions/random-reboots-on-x1-carbon-gen-11/m-p/5247585?page=4#6481002
For me on X1 it seems a Kernel regression between 6.7 -> 6.8, although I've had some more seldom crashes on 6.7 as well.

Is this finally a NVIDIA specific issue? I just got a ThinkPad P6s Gen2 AMD Ryzen / Radeon 780M laptop and considering the update to 24.04. I'm currently running Ubuntu Live USB 24.04 with few issues. The Linux 6.8.0-41-generic standard kernel works well, including 2nd display through USB, Wifi, Sound, webcam. Internal mic is very low. I was able to get acceptable mic level using pavucontrol.

Random poweroffs that occur without logging are a classic symptom of hardware fault(s). It's not a software feature (who would want that?)
Ubuntu cannot work properly on unreliable hardware.
Random poweroff are caused most commonly by overheating and by failing power supply.
There are many other less-common causes.

The thing is: I have precisely the same problem with 24.04 (same computer model, random resets while running 24.04), but it was working fine with 23.10, and actually it's still working fine with 24.04 when using the 6.5 kernel from 23.10. Sure it still could be a hardware problem, but clearly there is a software solution to this problem.

@progfou If you believe that you have found a software bug that is causing random poweroffs on a certain model of hardware, and you can describe how to reliably reproduce the behavior in enough detail for someone else to demonstrate in a test environment, then please file a proper bug report.

I'll do that as soon as I'm able to find how reproduce it forcefully!  For now, the only sure thing I have is: boot 24.04 with default 6.8 kernel and you'll have a reset at some random point in time, while working. But 24.04 with old Karmic 6.5 kernel and you'll be fine. It's not enough for a bug report to be helpful, IMHO. Or is it?

Maybe somebody else has reported a similar bug already. Have you looked?

Same machine, ubuntu 22.05, kernel 6.8.0-45-generic from backports. Random reboot every one or two days. No clear pattern of high load/high temperature. Run mostly with integrated graphics chip (I need to intentionaly activate the nvidia chip to offload a program to use it), so not sure it's graphics related. Also looking for ways to better reproduce and diagnose. Maybe remote-syslog?

I have the same issue with the exact same dmesg output. I have tested it on Wayland and X11 as you have, as well as xfce, unity and MATE on Mint.
I have also done a memtest and passed without error.
I am dual booting this PC on windows 11 and work all day everyday as my daily driver without any reboots or issues on windows. So it's not likely to be defective hardware as the commenter above claims.
One additional difference - I doubt it's related to your graphics card either, because I have the version with the onboard Vega graphics.

Hi Riley.
Thanks for you very appreciated answer. I am happy that I am not the only one having this problem. Altought, not good for you either...
I have dual boot as well with Win 11, but never use it. But good to know that the crashes are not there under Win, so it must be a software / driver issue.
Today, I tested with my RJ45 directly branched and the USB-Dongle for keyboard and mouse connected directly to the laptop and not to the Dell Display USB hub.
So far, I had no crashes... Fingers crossed.
Are you having a same setting? External display with USB Hub Cable by any chance?

Hi Riley. I just had another crash with just RJ-45, HDMI, oringinal power supply from Lenovo and a Logitech USB dongle for keyboard and mouse...
Will try to make tests without HDMI, but this i hard, since I need the big screen to work...
Keep me posted, if you have any news.

Ketos, iI get crashes with and without AC power. The most consistent factor is load. I can leave it all night idling and it won't reboot. After sometimes 30 minutes of heavy use, it will reboot. Usually right as I am starting to really get into my work for the day.

@RileyFlaherty Clarification please, what laptop model do you use exactly?

I had a similar issue with my Lenovo P14s running Ubuntu 24.04. My laptop would shut down unexpectedly and reboot with the fans running at full speed. This mostly occurred while connected to remote servers (VNC, RDP) but occasionally happened during lighter tasks like browsing or checking emails.
After troubleshooting, I suspected overheating was the culprit, causing the system to shut down and reboot to prevent damage. My workaround was to set the fan speed to a consistently high RPM. Since then, I haven't experienced any reboots.
While it’s not an ideal fix, it has worked for me. You can manually control fan speed using the method in this link.
I was able to get the laptop to consistently run with no reboots for entire workdays using RPM level #5:
echo level 5 | sudo tee /proc/acpi/ibm/fan

Hope this helps!

I’ve managed to achieve a stable setup, but only by using the NVIDIA driver 550 (proprietary) with Wayland. This setup runs smoothly, but I really miss Shutter, which unfortunately doesn’t work under Wayland.
On the other hand, when I switch to X11, I can only get it to work with the nouveau driver. The proprietary NVIDIA driver causes bugs and lags in X11. While Shutter works fine with X11 and nouveau, I still face random reboots.
I also tried pressing the hardware reset button (the tiny one on the bottom of the laptop) for a few seconds, which might have helped, but I’m not entirely sure.
The post from fxx resonates with my experience. My question is, has anyone managed to get X11 working smoothly with the proprietary NVIDIA driver? If so, I’d love to hear your setup.

I have the same problem on my 21HF000SGE (i7-1360P, RTX A500, 32GB) running Linux Mint 22 (based on Ubuntu 24.04, kernel 6.8.0-47-generic) with Cinnamon on X11. It happened even with a freshly booted Live USB stick, and both with official and third party power adapters, as well as in battery mode. I also have the HANDLING IBECC MEMORY ERROR in my system logs, if that has anything to do with anything.
Following discussions in the Arch Linux Forum, NVidia Forum, on Reddit and elsewhere, I suspected the NVidia 550 driver to be the culprit. But after I downgraded to 535, I had two resets again today. 535 ran the whole day without issues (stationary), but crashed after using it on my lap for a while. 550 felt much less stable, even stationary, but this is really only anecdotal...
What kind of seems to help, is setting the graphics driver to only use the NVidia GPU (sudo prime-select nvidia).
Since there is really nothing useful in the system logs, my suspicion is that there is a thermal or another hardware issue... that is only triggered by some workloads and more frequently with the newer drivers (maybe related to the bugs in the linked forums).

Same issues here. Appeared ~2 months ago. Looks like it was the time it went from 6.5 to 6.8 kernel. I did not find anything systematic in any logs. Did run memtest86+ - no issues found. All BIOS hardware tests pass. I tried looking at temperature sensors as fast as I could after a reboot and the temperature seems completely normal (the same range as during normal non-heavy work).

OS : Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS
PC model: Lenovo ThinkPad P16s Gen 2
GPU: Integrated Intel® Iris® Xe Graphics
CPU: 13th Generation Intel® Core™ i7-1370P vPro® Processor
RAM: 32 GB DDR5-5200MHz (16 GB Soldered + 16 GB SODIMM)

I have a dual boot to Win11 and I had no crashes there.

I've been having the same issue for about a month.

pc model: Lenovo ThinkPad P14s Gen 4
gpu: NV177 / Mesa Intel®Graphics (RPL-P)
cpu: 13th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-1370P × 20
mem:32,0 GiB

I noticed it can crash when memory is very low because of few crashes in a row where I only had the time to start back chrome.
As explained, sometime it can work for few days without restart and some days I have 5 restarts. Fan makes no noise and it doesn't restart when I open an application or start a heavy process. It just looks random and I have nothing in logs so it doesn't look like software failure.
I noticed the HANDLING IBECC MEMORY ERROR as well.

This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can follow this question. Once you have enough reputation, you can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question. - From Review


The error logs show quite a lot of errors. Especially the HANDLING IBECC MEMORY ERROR was telling me maybe a memory error.

Based upon the dmesg sample the HANDLING IBECC MEMORY ERROR is reported relatively "early" during boot with a timestamp of 5.8 seconds. Re: EDAC igen6 error messages at boot suggests this error was found to be spurious due to the way the In-band ECC error log is initialised, and that a Kernel patch was prepared to remove the spurious errors on driver load (this contains the error messages). Albeit I haven't yet checked which Kernel version the patch has been made available in.
While the grep -i "error\|fail" /var/log/kern.log in the question shows two sets of HANDLING IBECC MEMORY ERROR for both EDAC igen6 MC0 and EDAC igen6 MC1:

Both sets of errors have a timestamp a few hundred microseconds later than a preceding RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized. message.
The /var/log/kern.log on an a different computer running Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS shows that log file contains messages over multiple boots.

While this answer doesn't help to explain the cause of the random reboots, it is just to say that believe the HANDLING IBECC MEMORY ERROR is spuriously reported at boot up, rather than leading to the reboots.

I experienced the same issue with my laptop from work a Lenovo ThinkPad P16s Gen 2 (i7-1370P, nvidia RTX A500, 64GB) running Linux Mint 21.3 with 6.8.0.47 kernel. Our ServiceDesk IT opened up the laptop and discovered that the heatsink on the SSD was not attached properly, also the thermal paste on the CPU had turned into solid putty instead of being a paste.
Having fixed both of these problems the random restarts remained. Two weeks later I received a brand new Lenovo ThinkPad P16s, because they thought that the SSD could be damaged due to overheating.
I reinstalled everything and still got random restarts with no messages in journalctl or crash reports. Then I remember that the problems started, when switching from kernel 6.5 to 6.8. Having tried many distros (Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS, Ubuntu 24.04, Linux Mint 22) all suffered from random restarts, but then they all have kernel 6.8. Finally I installed Linux Mint 21.3 Edge, which installs with a 6.5 kernel. Updated it to the last available version 6.5.0-45 kernel and have not had any random restarts since.
Of course components in a laptop can get broken. However, two brand new laptops in a row from different production series is highly unlikely (and I am a statistician with a PhD in data analysis). Therefore, my conclusion is that there something with the 6.8 kernel that causes these random reboots.
[update 20-11-2024] I installed Ubuntu 24.10, which uses the 6.11 kernel. This results again in a stable system, with no reboots!

I had the same issue. As heio already wrote in another answer, it was related to the graphics card/driver settings. After I ran "nvidia-settings" in bash, navigated to PRIME Profiles and changed from On-Demand to Performance-Mode, I never encountered the problem again. Not sure whats the root of the problem though.
